# how could change element class in media query

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

```
<button id='123'  type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</button>


@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) { .... }
```

I hope in min-width:600px , 
change the Button id='123' class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"

Please Help me !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not change the class of an element with media queries. But instead you can switch between 2 different buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger visible-xs-block">
   <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn someOtherClass hidden-xs">
   <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</button>
```

to implement this there are predefined bootstrap helper classes which can show / hide elements dependent on screen size. In your case *visible-xs* will show the element only on small screens and *hidden-xs* will hide the element on larger screens.

Comment: A bad practice promoted by Bootstrap.

Comment: I do not understand how it makes sense to duplicate the entire DOM tree just to support responsive screens. Listening to resize event just seems better using the [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) function

Answer (score 10):

You cannot change the list of classes of an element using CSS. You can however change the definition of a css class using mediaqueries.

If you want to change one or more classes on an element, you can use jQuery like this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  var win = $(this);
  if (win.width() > 600) {

    $('#123').addClass('btn-lg');

  } else {
    $('#123').removeClass('btn-lg');
  }
});
```